# Tableau: is it possible to prevent a color gradient from updating when a filter is selected?

Tags: filter, tableau-api, gradient

Let's say I have a heat map of percentages, and I've assigned a blue-orange gradient, so 100% is blue, 0% is orange, and everything in between is a shade of one of those colors.

Now, if I select a filter that removes every value higher than 50%, the gradient will update. 0% is still orange, but now 50% is the darkest blue.

Is it possible to preserve the colors that are assigned when all the data is included, regardless of how it's filtered? I want to be able to filter to the bottom 25%, and have all of those values still be orange.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to double click on your gradient and set manual start, end, and mid points by clicking the advanced button.
[image]